# How can i import all google font at once?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, google-font-api

I want help on importing all of Google web font at once ,
I tested the normal 'link rel' in my head tag to import The Family Tangerine for my post and it worked perfectly.
Although i want a way in which i can import all the fonts available,  so i can use them whenever i want , do i have to write them one by one or is there any full embedded link rel for all of them .
Pease help me out.

Comment: You cannot, essentially, import every single font from a font library. You will have to choose which ones you want to use. Do I miss something from your question?

Comment: You can only get every font by selecting them from fonts.google.com

Comment: You can do it with Easy Fonts. See: https://pagecdn.com/lib/easyfonts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import all Google Fonts to your website using the [Easy Fonts](https://pagecdn.com/lib/easyfonts) library. All you have to do is import the following CSS file:

```
<link href="https://pagecdn.io/lib/easyfonts/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and, then use the fonts the way you want. Additionally, you can also use the font families and font weights using CSS classes as below:

```
<div class="font-lato w500i">
    <a class="font-open-sans w700" href="https://google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

Full class reference for each font family is available [here](https://pagecdn.com/lib/easyfonts).

Comment: Not sure if this works anymore. The CDN for this has been down for a while.

Answer (score 7):

Hmm, it will result in an extremely large file being imported, and Google may even disallow it, but I guess you could select every font from the list. I've selected 101 of the fonts and it seems to work ok.

Go to https://fonts.google.com/ and start clicking every, single, font, and every, single, font weight (better get some food and drink ready, it might take a day or two) Google will provide a `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=` with all the fonts appended. Add this to your page, then you can define the `font-family` for an element using any of the font names.

```css
/*
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Zilla Slab Highlight', cursive;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Spectral', serif;
font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
font-family: 'Saira Condensed', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Saira', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Saira Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Julee', cursive;
font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Lora', serif;
font-family: 'Manuale', serif;
font-family: 'Asap Condensed', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Faustina', serif;
font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;
font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Sedgwick Ave Display', cursive;
font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Sedgwick Ave', cursive;
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
font-family: 'Mada', sans-serif;
font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
font-family: 'Bowlby One SC', cursive;
font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;
font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Sedgwick Ave Display', cursive;
font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Sedgwick Ave', cursive;
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
font-family: 'Mada', sans-serif;
font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
font-family: 'Bowlby One SC', cursive;
font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Acme', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Mukta Vaani', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;
font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
font-family: 'Libre Franklin', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Crete Round', serif;
font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;
font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
*/
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Abril+Fatface|Acme|Alegreya|Alegreya+Sans|Anton|Archivo|Archivo+Black|Archivo+Narrow|Arimo|Arvo|Asap|Asap+Condensed|Bitter|Bowlby+One+SC|Bree+Serif|Cabin|Cairo|Catamaran|Crete+Round|Crimson+Text|Cuprum|Dancing+Script|Dosis|Droid+Sans|Droid+Serif|EB+Garamond|Exo|Exo+2|Faustina|Fira+Sans|Fjalla+One|Francois+One|Gloria+Hallelujah|Hind|Inconsolata|Indie+Flower|Josefin+Sans|Julee|Karla|Lato|Libre+Baskerville|Libre+Franklin|Lobster|Lora|Mada|Manuale|Maven+Pro|Merriweather|Merriweather+Sans|Montserrat|Montserrat+Subrayada|Mukta+Vaani|Muli|Noto+Sans|Noto+Serif|Nunito|Open+Sans|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Oswald|Oxygen|PT+Sans|PT+Sans+Caption|PT+Sans+Narrow|PT+Serif|Pacifico|Passion+One|Pathway+Gothic+One|Play|Playfair+Display|Poppins|Questrial|Quicksand|Raleway|Roboto|Roboto+Condensed|Roboto+Mono|Roboto+Slab|Ropa+Sans|Rubik|Saira|Saira+Condensed|Saira+Extra+Condensed|Saira+Semi+Condensed|Sedgwick+Ave|Sedgwick+Ave+Display|Shadows+Into+Light|Signika|Slabo+27px|Source+Code+Pro|Source+Sans+Pro|Spectral|Titillium+Web|Ubuntu|Ubuntu+Condensed|Varela+Round|Vollkorn|Work+Sans|Yanone+Kaffeesatz|Zilla+Slab|Zilla+Slab+Highlight" rel="stylesheet">
```

An alternate, and much more performant solution, might be to use the [Google Web Font Loader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) which allows you to load any of the Google fonts via JS. This would allo you to load *ANY* of the Google fonts, without loading *ALL* of the Google fonts.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js">    </script>
<script>
  WebFont.load({
    google: {
      families: ['Any Google Font']
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You still have to get the names of the Google Fonts, so how do you get all the names in a straightforward way without spending the day or two clicking the site haha.

Answer (score 1):

You can load multiple google font's but you have to define font families for every font you want to import. You need to separate each font using '|' character.

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Brawler|Ubuntu|Righteous' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 1):

- I was using google api to get all fonts:
  https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=YOUR-API-KEY
- Copy only font family names. I was using VS Code and Regular Expression.
- Replace space with + to build stylesheet link:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=ABeeZee|Abel|Abhaya+Libre|Abril+Fatface|Aclonica|Acme|Actor|Adamina|Advent+Pro|Aguafina+Script|Akaya+Kanadaka|Akaya+Telivigala|Akronim|Aladin|Alata|Alatsi|Aldrich|Alef|Alegreya|Alegreya+SC|Alegreya+Sans|Alegreya+Sans+SC|Aleo|Alex+Brush|Alfa+Slab+One|Alice|Alike|Alike+Angular|Allan|Allerta|Allerta+Stencil|Allura|Almarai|Almendra|Almendra+Display|Almendra+SC|Amarante|Amaranth|Amatic+SC|Amethysta|Amiko|Amiri|Amita|Anaheim|Andada|Andika|Andika+New+Basic|Angkor|Annie+Use+Your+Telescope|Anonymous+Pro|Antic|Antic+Didone|Antic+Slab|Anton|Antonio|Arapey|Arbutus|Arbutus+Slab|Architects+Daughter|Archivo|Archivo+Black|Archivo+Narrow|Aref+Ruqaa|Arima+Madurai|Arimo|Arizonia|Armata|Arsenal|Artifika|Arvo|Arya|Asap|Asap+Condensed|Asar|Asset|Assistant|Astloch|Asul|Athiti|Atma|Atomic+Age|Aubrey|Audiowide|Autour+One|Average|Average+Sans|Averia+Gruesa+Libre|Averia+Libre|Averia+Sans+Libre|Averia+Serif+Libre|B612|B612+Mono|Bad+Script|Bahiana|Bahianita|Bai+Jamjuree|Ballet|Baloo+2|Baloo+Bhai+2|Baloo+Bhaina+2|Baloo+Chettan+2|Baloo+Da+2|Baloo+Paaji+2|Baloo+Tamma+2|Baloo+Tammudu+2|Baloo+Thambi+2|Balsamiq+Sans|Balthazar|Bangers|Barlow|Barlow+Condensed|Barlow+Semi+Condensed|Barriecito|Barrio|Basic|Baskervville|Battambang|Baumans|Bayon|Be+Vietnam|Bebas+Neue|Belgrano|Bellefair|Belleza|Bellota|Bellota+Text|BenchNine|Benne|Bentham|Berkshire+Swash|Beth+Ellen|Bevan|Big+Shoulders+Display|Big+Shoulders+Inline+Display|Big+Shoulders+Inline+Text|Big+Shoulders+Stencil+Display|Big+Shoulders+Stencil+Text|Big+Shoulders+Text|Bigelow+Rules|Bigshot+One|Bilbo|Bilbo+Swash+Caps|BioRhyme|BioRhyme+Expanded|Biryani|Bitter|Black+And+White+Picture|Black+Han+Sans|Black+Ops+One|Blinker|Bodoni+Moda|Bokor|Bonbon|Boogaloo|Bowlby+One|Bowlby+One+SC|Brawler|Bree+Serif|Brygada+1918|Bubblegum+Sans|Bubbler+One|Buda|Buenard|Bungee|Bungee+Hairline|Bungee+Inline|Bungee+Outline|Bungee+Shade|Butcherman|Butterfly+Kids|Cabin|Cabin+Condensed|Cabin+Sketch|Caesar+Dressing|Cagliostro|Cairo|Caladea|Calistoga|Calligraffitti|Cambay|Cambo|Candal|Cantarell|Cantata+One|Cantora+One|Capriola|Cardo|Carme|Carrois+Gothic|Carrois+Gothic+SC|Carter+One|Castoro|Catamaran|Caudex|Caveat|Caveat+Brush|Cedarville+Cursive|Ceviche+One|Chakra+Petch|Changa|Changa+One|Chango|Charm|Charmonman|Chathura|Chau+Philomene+One|Chela+One|Chelsea+Market|Chenla|Cherry+Cream+Soda|Cherry+Swash|Chewy|Chicle|Chilanka|Chivo|Chonburi|Cinzel|Cinzel+Decorative|Clicker+Script|Coda|Coda+Caption|Codystar|Coiny|Combo|Comfortaa|Comic+Neue|Coming+Soon|Commissioner|Concert+One|Condiment|Content|Contrail+One|Convergence|Cookie|Copse|Corben|Cormorant|Cormorant+Garamond|Cormorant+Infant|Cormorant+SC|Cormorant+Unicase|Cormorant+Upright|Courgette|Courier+Prime|Cousine|Coustard|Covered+By+Your+Grace|Crafty+Girls|Creepster|Crete+Round|Crimson+Pro|Crimson+Text|Croissant+One|Crushed|Cuprum|Cute+Font|Cutive|Cutive+Mono|DM+Mono|DM+Sans|DM+Serif+Display|DM+Serif+Text|Damion|Dancing+Script|Dangrek|Darker+Grotesque|David+Libre|Dawning+of+a+New+Day|Days+One|Dekko|Dela+Gothic+One|Delius|Delius+Swash+Caps|Delius+Unicase|Della+Respira|Denk+One|Devonshire|Dhurjati|Didact+Gothic|Diplomata|Diplomata+SC|Do+Hyeon|Dokdo|Domine|Donegal+One|Doppio+One|Dorsa|Dosis|DotGothic16|Dr+Sugiyama|Duru+Sans|Dynalight|EB+Garamond|Eagle+Lake|East+Sea+Dokdo|Eater|Economica|Eczar|El+Messiri|Electrolize|Elsie|Elsie+Swash+Caps|Emblema+One|Emilys+Candy|Encode+Sans|Encode+Sans+Condensed|Encode+Sans+Expanded|Encode+Sans+Semi+Condensed|Encode+Sans+Semi+Expanded|Engagement|Englebert|Enriqueta|Epilogue|Erica+One|Esteban|Euphoria+Script|Ewert|Exo|Exo+2|Expletus+Sans|Fahkwang|Fanwood+Text|Farro|Farsan|Fascinate|Fascinate+Inline|Faster+One|Fasthand|Fauna+One|Faustina|Federant|Federo|Felipa|Fenix|Finger+Paint|Fira+Code|Fira+Mono|Fira+Sans|Fira+Sans+Condensed|Fira+Sans+Extra+Condensed|Fjalla+One|Fjord+One|Flamenco|Flavors|Fondamento|Fontdiner+Swanky|Forum|Francois+One|Frank+Ruhl+Libre|Fraunces|Freckle+Face|Fredericka+the+Great|Fredoka+One|Freehand|Fresca|Frijole|Fruktur|Fugaz+One|GFS+Didot|GFS+Neohellenic|Gabriela|Gaegu|Gafata|Galada|Galdeano|Galindo|Gamja+Flower|Gayathri|Gelasio|Gentium+Basic|Gentium+Book+Basic|Geo|Geostar|Geostar+Fill|Germania+One|Gidugu|Gilda+Display|Girassol|Give+You+Glory|Glass+Antiqua|Glegoo|Gloria+Hallelujah|Goblin+One|Gochi+Hand|Goldman|Gorditas|Gothic+A1|Gotu|Goudy+Bookletter+1911|Graduate|Grand+Hotel|Grandstander|Gravitas+One|Great+Vibes|Grenze|Grenze+Gotisch|Griffy|Gruppo|Gudea|Gugi|Gupter|Gurajada|Habibi|Hachi+Maru+Pop|Halant|Hammersmith+One|Hanalei|Hanalei+Fill|Handlee|Hanuman|Happy+Monkey|Harmattan|Headland+One|Heebo|Henny+Penny|Hepta+Slab|Herr+Von+Muellerhoff|Hi+Melody|Hind|Hind+Guntur|Hind+Madurai|Hind+Siliguri|Hind+Vadodara|Holtwood+One+SC|Homemade+Apple|Homenaje|IBM+Plex+Mono|IBM+Plex+Sans|IBM+Plex+Sans+Condensed|IBM+Plex+Serif|IM+Fell+DW+Pica|IM+Fell+DW+Pica+SC|IM+Fell+Double+Pica|IM+Fell+Double+Pica+SC|IM+Fell+English|IM+Fell+English+SC|IM+Fell+French+Canon|IM+Fell+French+Canon+SC|IM+Fell+Great+Primer|IM+Fell+Great+Primer+SC|Ibarra+Real+Nova|Iceberg|Iceland|Imbue|Imprima|Inconsolata|Inder|Indie+Flower|Inika|Inknut+Antiqua|Inria+Sans|Inria+Serif|Inter|Irish+Grover|Istok+Web|Italiana|Italianno|Itim|Jacques+Francois|Jacques+Francois+Shadow|Jaldi|JetBrains+Mono|Jim+Nightshade|Jockey+One|Jolly+Lodger|Jomhuria|Jomolhari|Josefin+Sans|Josefin+Slab|Jost|Joti+One|Jua|Judson|Julee|Julius+Sans+One|Junge|Jura|Just+Another+Hand|Just+Me+Again+Down+Here|K2D|Kadwa|Kalam|Kameron|Kanit|Kantumruy|Karantina|Karla|Karma|Katibeh|Kaushan+Script|Kavivanar|Kavoon|Kdam+Thmor|Keania+One|Kelly+Slab|Kenia|Khand|Khmer|Khula|Kirang+Haerang|Kite+One|Kiwi+Maru|Knewave|KoHo|Kodchasan|Kosugi|Kosugi+Maru|Kotta+One|Koulen|Kranky|Kreon|Kristi|Krona+One|Krub|Kufam|Kulim+Park|Kumar+One|Kumar+One+Outline|Kumbh+Sans|Kurale|La+Belle+Aurore|Lacquer|Laila|Lakki+Reddy|Lalezar|Lancelot|Langar|Lateef|Lato|League+Script|Leckerli+One|Ledger|Lekton|Lemon|Lemonada|Lexend|Lexend+Deca|Lexend+Exa|Lexend+Giga|Lexend+Mega|Lexend+Peta|Lexend+Tera|Lexend+Zetta|Libre+Barcode+128|Libre+Barcode+128+Text|Libre+Barcode+39|Libre+Barcode+39+Extended|Libre+Barcode+39+Extended+Text|Libre+Barcode+39+Text|Libre+Barcode+EAN13+Text|Libre+Baskerville|Libre+Caslon+Display|Libre+Caslon+Text|Libre+Franklin|Life+Savers|Lilita+One|Lily+Script+One|Limelight|Linden+Hill|Literata|Liu+Jian+Mao+Cao|Livvic|Lobster|Lobster+Two|Londrina+Outline|Londrina+Shadow|Londrina+Sketch|Londrina+Solid|Long+Cang|Lora|Love+Ya+Like+A+Sister|Loved+by+the+King|Lovers+Quarrel|Luckiest+Guy|Lusitana|Lustria|M+PLUS+1p|M+PLUS+Rounded+1c|Ma+Shan+Zheng|Macondo|Macondo+Swash+Caps|Mada|Magra|Maiden+Orange|Maitree|Major+Mono+Display|Mako|Mali|Mallanna|Mandali|Manjari|Manrope|Mansalva|Manuale|Marcellus|Marcellus+SC|Marck+Script|Margarine|Markazi+Text|Marko+One|Marmelad|Martel|Martel+Sans|Marvel|Mate|Mate+SC|Maven+Pro|McLaren|Meddon|MedievalSharp|Medula+One|Meera+Inimai|Megrim|Meie+Script|Merienda|Merienda+One|Merriweather|Merriweather+Sans|Metal|Metal+Mania|Metamorphous|Metrophobic|Michroma|Milonga|Miltonian|Miltonian+Tattoo|Mina|Miniver|Miriam+Libre|Mirza|Miss+Fajardose|Mitr|Modak|Modern+Antiqua|Mogra|Molengo|Molle|Monda|Monofett|Monoton|Monsieur+La+Doulaise|Montaga|Montez|Montserrat|Montserrat+Alternates|Montserrat+Subrayada|Moul|Moulpali|Mountains+of+Christmas|Mouse+Memoirs|Mr+Bedfort|Mr+Dafoe|Mr+De+Haviland|Mrs+Saint+Delafield|Mrs+Sheppards|Mukta|Mukta+Mahee|Mukta+Malar|Mukta+Vaani|Mulish|MuseoModerno|Mystery+Quest|NTR|Nanum+Brush+Script|Nanum+Gothic|Nanum+Gothic+Coding|Nanum+Myeongjo|Nanum+Pen+Script|Nerko+One|Neucha|Neuton|New+Rocker|New+Tegomin|News+Cycle|Newsreader|Niconne|Niramit|Nixie+One|Nobile|Nokora|Norican|Nosifer|Notable|Nothing+You+Could+Do|Noticia+Text|Noto+Sans|Noto+Sans+HK|Noto+Sans+JP|Noto+Sans+KR|Noto+Sans+SC|Noto+Sans+TC|Noto+Serif|Noto+Serif+JP|Noto+Serif+KR|Noto+Serif+SC|Noto+Serif+TC|Nova+Cut|Nova+Flat|Nova+Mono|Nova+Oval|Nova+Round|Nova+Script|Nova+Slim|Nova+Square|Numans|Nunito|Nunito+Sans|Odibee+Sans|Odor+Mean+Chey|Offside|Oi|Old+Standard+TT|Oldenburg|Oleo+Script|Oleo+Script+Swash+Caps|Open+Sans|Open+Sans+Condensed|Oranienbaum|Orbitron|Oregano|Orelega+One|Orienta|Original+Surfer|Oswald|Over+the+Rainbow|Overlock|Overlock+SC|Overpass|Overpass+Mono|Ovo|Oxanium|Oxygen|Oxygen+Mono|PT+Mono|PT+Sans|PT+Sans+Caption|PT+Sans+Narrow|PT+Serif|PT+Serif+Caption|Pacifico|Padauk|Palanquin|Palanquin+Dark|Pangolin|Paprika|Parisienne|Passero+One|Passion+One|Pathway+Gothic+One|Patrick+Hand|Patrick+Hand+SC|Pattaya|Patua+One|Pavanam|Paytone+One|Peddana|Peralta|Permanent+Marker|Petit+Formal+Script|Petrona|Philosopher|Piazzolla|Piedra|Pinyon+Script|Pirata+One|Plaster|Play|Playball|Playfair+Display|Playfair+Display+SC|Podkova|Poiret+One|Poller+One|Poly|Pompiere|Pontano+Sans|Poor+Story|Poppins|Port+Lligat+Sans|Port+Lligat+Slab|Potta+One|Pragati+Narrow|Prata|Preahvihear|Press+Start+2P|Pridi|Princess+Sofia|Prociono|Prompt|Prosto+One|Proza+Libre|Public+Sans|Puritan|Purple+Purse|Quando|Quantico|Quattrocento|Quattrocento+Sans|Questrial|Quicksand|Quintessential|Qwigley|Racing+Sans+One|Radley|Rajdhani|Rakkas|Raleway|Raleway+Dots|Ramabhadra|Ramaraja|Rambla|Rammetto+One|Ranchers|Rancho|Ranga|Rasa|Rationale|Ravi+Prakash|Recursive|Red+Hat+Display|Red+Hat+Text|Red+Rose|Redressed|Reem+Kufi|Reenie+Beanie|Reggae+One|Revalia|Rhodium+Libre|Ribeye|Ribeye+Marrow|Righteous|Risque|Roboto|Roboto+Condensed|Roboto+Mono|Roboto+Slab|Rochester|Rock+Salt|RocknRoll+One|Rokkitt|Romanesco|Ropa+Sans|Rosario|Rosarivo|Rouge+Script|Rowdies|Rozha+One|Rubik|Rubik+Mono+One|Ruda|Rufina|Ruge+Boogie|Ruluko|Rum+Raisin|Ruslan+Display|Russo+One|Ruthie|Rye|Sacramento|Sahitya|Sail|Saira|Saira+Condensed|Saira+Extra+Condensed|Saira+Semi+Condensed|Saira+Stencil+One|Salsa|Sanchez|Sancreek|Sansita|Sansita+Swashed|Sarabun|Sarala|Sarina|Sarpanch|Satisfy|Sawarabi+Gothic|Sawarabi+Mincho|Scada|Scheherazade|Schoolbell|Scope+One|Seaweed+Script|Secular+One|Sedgwick+Ave|Sedgwick+Ave+Display|Sen|Sevillana|Seymour+One|Shadows+Into+Light|Shadows+Into+Light+Two|Shanti|Share|Share+Tech|Share+Tech+Mono|Shippori+Mincho|Shippori+Mincho+B1|Shojumaru|Short+Stack|Shrikhand|Siemreap|Sigmar+One|Signika|Signika+Negative|Simonetta|Single+Day|Sintony|Sirin+Stencil|Six+Caps|Skranji|Slabo+13px|Slabo+27px|Slackey|Smokum|Smythe|Sniglet|Snippet|Snowburst+One|Sofadi+One|Sofia|Solway|Song+Myung|Sonsie+One|Sora|Sorts+Mill+Goudy|Source+Code+Pro|Source+Sans+Pro|Source+Serif+Pro|Space+Grotesk|Space+Mono|Spartan|Special+Elite|Spectral|Spectral+SC|Spicy+Rice|Spinnaker|Spirax|Squada+One|Sree+Krushnadevaraya|Sriracha|Srisakdi|Staatliches|Stalemate|Stalinist+One|Stardos+Stencil|Stick|Stint+Ultra+Condensed|Stint+Ultra+Expanded|Stoke|Strait|Stylish|Sue+Ellen+Francisco|Suez+One|Sulphur+Point|Sumana|Sunflower|Sunshiney|Supermercado+One|Sura|Suranna|Suravaram|Suwannaphum|Swanky+and+Moo+Moo|Syncopate|Syne|Syne+Mono|Syne+Tactile|Tajawal|Tangerine|Taprom|Tauri|Taviraj|Teko|Telex|Tenali+Ramakrishna|Tenor+Sans|Text+Me+One|Texturina|Thasadith|The+Girl+Next+Door|Tienne|Tillana|Timmana|Tinos|Titan+One|Titillium+Web|Tomorrow|Trade+Winds|Train+One|Trirong|Trispace|Trocchi|Trochut|Truculenta|Trykker|Tulpen+One|Turret+Road|Ubuntu|Ubuntu+Condensed|Ubuntu+Mono|Ultra|Uncial+Antiqua|Underdog|Unica+One|UnifrakturCook|UnifrakturMaguntia|Unkempt|Unlock|Unna|VT323|Vampiro+One|Varela|Varela+Round|Varta|Vast+Shadow|Vesper+Libre|Viaoda+Libre|Vibes|Vibur|Vidaloka|Viga|Voces|Volkhov|Vollkorn|Vollkorn+SC|Voltaire|Waiting+for+the+Sunrise|Wallpoet|Walter+Turncoat|Warnes|Wellfleet|Wendy+One|Wire+One|Work+Sans|Xanh+Mono|Yanone+Kaffeesatz|Yantramanav|Yatra+One|Yellowtail|Yeon+Sung|Yeseva+One|Yesteryear|Yrsa|Yusei+Magic|ZCOOL+KuaiLe|ZCOOL+QingKe+HuangYou|ZCOOL+XiaoWei|Zen+Dots|Zeyada|Zhi+Mang+Xing|Zilla+Slab|Zilla+Slab+Highlight">
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a font from the google font library is essentially adding a style-sheet every time to your page that needs to be downloaded *every time* your site loads.

There's no shortcut to download *all* google fonts to a single website because the inefficiency of having a ginormous amount of CSS downloaded when your page is accessed simply isn't the best solution. Professional web developers have a specific font-stack for each website and only include those specific fonts used in that page. This is my suggestion.