# Select all styles from Google Fonts

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

This might be a stupid question, but I wanted to know if there's a way to select all styles of any given font with **one click**, without having to **click each individual style** (Thin 100, Thin 100 Italic, and so on). I can't find a "Select all" option or something like that, so I wanted to know if it's just not there or if I'm not seeing it.

Just to be clear: this is for importing into a .css, I don't want to download the family!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i import all google font at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45487014/how-can-i-import-all-google-font-at-once)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, that question asks if you can import all Google fonts, I was wondering if you can select all styles from an individual family at once. I'm guessing you can't! In any case, it was just a doubt, nothing super important :).

Answer (score 4):

I think google removed the possibility to add an entire family (They don't want you to overload your project), but there still a way.

Simply add a style or two of the family, then remove all the style in the code by hand.

So here I have 
`family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;1,100;1,200`

Simply remove everything after the column like this 
`family=Montserrat`

You can do the same no matter how many families you have.

i.e.: 
`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;1,100;1,200&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

I'll write :

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Sorry, but that's not correct. If you omit width and style query params the url will only return `@font-face` rules for regular (font-weight:400) style

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you go to [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) and find the font you want.
Then you select "Type Tester".
Roll down the screen and select all the styles you want.
At the side table, select import, copy the code and paste to your css sheet.

Here's an image to try and help.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I know how to select them one by one. What I wanted to know if there was a way to just select them all with one click, instead of selecting them one by one.

Comment: I think not, because you might not want to use all of them on your website. And they do consume storage in your css file. This makes your website slower to load.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Steven G doesn't seem to work, or it doesn't any longer.

In my testing, if you remove all the individual weights then you only get a normal and bold version of the font.  To get all the weights you'll need to add them individually.

In other words, you should just use the code the way Google provides it when you select the font styles from their webpage.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35461097)